# Android: Could not find jetifier-processor library. Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, gradle, classpath

I'm trying to sync Project but got this error:

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta04.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta04).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta04/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta04.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta04.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta04/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta04.jar
```

Here I post my files:

-build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

-gradle-wrapper.property

```
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

-app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.roomcoursecodingwithmitch"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

   implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'

   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'


    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Annotation processor
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"

   testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"

    implementation "androidx.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09"

    implementation "androidx.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09"
}
```

Any Idea? I've tried to update the jetifier library to beta-09, but no matter I include it in the dependencies this error appears over and over again.

I even commented on all the dependencies but this `jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04` error is present all the time.

Any clue?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. download the latest Gradle version
2. go to setting > build > build tools > Gradle
3. use "specified location" and set the address of your Gradle
4. sync Gradle again

it worked for me.